# Hive on Spark StackOverFlow Error

Tags: apache-spark, hive, cloudera

i am running Hive on Spark on CDH 5.10. and i get the below error. I have checked all the logs of YARN , Hive and Spark, but there is no useful information apart from the below error:

Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, xxx.local, executor 1): java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: You might want to look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20SPARK%20AND%20summary%20~%20StackOverflowError?  There are 19 issues (6 still open) with Spark generating java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 1):

Tyr to set the following parameters before executing your query:

```
set spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xss16m;
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
```